# DRF, Firebase FCM. Sending push notifications

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a DRF project and want to implement sending push notifications to devices.

I have configured firebase in Django settings. But after that I faced a problem as I can't send test notification even from admin, I get an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaLx0.png)

I understand that FCM registration token is required, but there is no way I can get it on backend side. Please advise if anyone has come across how is it possible to generate registration token on backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the token on front.end side with JS, and also have functions for receiving messages in background/foreground on front.end.
The token can then be saved in your database or on firebase, whichever you prefer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).